# Listen for changes in DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a reflection of part of my website. This is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id = "original">
    <img src = "picture.png" alt = "A picture" id = "picture">
    <p id = "text">Some text</p>
</div>
<div id = "reflection"></div>
```

My Idea is copying the content of div#original to div#reflection like this:

```
<script>
    function reflect()
    {
        var original = document.getElementById("original");
        var reflection = document.getElementById("reflection");
        reflection.innerHTML = original.innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

***I am aware, that this will make the HTML invalid, in the whole project I iterate through the elements copied and set the IDs to not have that side effect. I just thought that this would be unnecessary to include here.***

The problem I have is that the HTML I want to reflect is dynamic, so it may change. Then the reflection is wrong. I have searched for an event handler for this, but haven't found one. The only one near I found was onchange, but apparently this listens to changes in the attributes, not the child elements. Is there another one for this, or did I just use onchange wrong?

Thank you for your help!
GeF

*I am aware that I could add onchange to every element, but this seemed not good style to me.*

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Are you saying it won't be invalid @nicael? Because it will.

Comment: @putvande He shows valid code.. No?

Comment: It is valid code, but by copying the `innerHTML` of `#original` and pasting it in `#reflection` you will have element that have the same ID, which does make it invalid.

Comment: Sorry, I just accidentally hit Submit instead of Preview. Is that so bad to give me 4 down votes? Or is the question bad? I don't really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is add a callback to `reflect()` every time you change the contents of the `#original`.

If this is not an option, you can look into a `MutationObserver` ([documetation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)), as suggested here: [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/)